# Past perfect tense example

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, sentence-construction, word-request

I passed high-school in 16 years old and later I joined Army. When I was 21 years old I had been an officer.

Could I use past perfect as completed action above when I was 21 years old I had been an officer.

Comment: *When I was 21 years old I had been an officer* is not idiomatic. Were you still in the Army at 21? Did you become an officer *before* you were 21? Assuming the answers to those are *"Yes"* and *"No",* it would be more natural to say *"By [the time I was] 21, I was an officer"*. If your answers are different, I'm not sure what you're trying to say anyway. Most importantly, I see *no reason at all* to think about using a Past Perfect verb form anywhere here. There is no "Past within the Past" to justify it.

Comment: "I _left_ high school _at_ 16 and joined the Army." _Later_ implies that you did something else in between - I don't know if that's what you meant.